Security.stripInaccessible() remove a field that I need
This method is removing a field that I need to make the upsert, is a field that isn't writable but is stuffed in the code.
if(customFee.orderFee.Quote__c == null){
        customFee.orderFee.Quote__c = recordId;
    }
    actualOrderFee.add(customFee.orderFee);
    upsert Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.UPSERTABLE, actualOrderFee).getRecords();

I have all the permissions of the field.
I need to use that field because is a master-detail field that i need to make the relation of two objects.
I try to find in google some information and all that i see is wrong for this case, other way i try to make a insert or an update and the error doesn't dissapear.

The problem arises when performing an upsert on a record with a non-editable master-detail field where the field is required. A stripInaccessible UPSERTABLE operation discards non-editable fields, and since the field is required, it causes an error. The solution is to separate the records into two lists: one for updating and another for inserting, using a stripInaccessible UPDATABLE for updates and another CREATABLE for inserts.
